# Wordpress - managing event listings?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an events page that uses the following query:

```
<?php $portfolioloop = new WP_Query( array( 'post__not_in' => array(4269), 'paged' => get_query_var('paged'), 'post_status' => 'future', 'post_type' => 'whatson', 'exclude' => '4269', 'posts_per_page' => 20, 'order' => 'ASC')); ?>
```

All this does is show a list of all scheduled custom posts and when the post hits the scheduled date it publishes the page... thus removing it from the list.

It's nearly what I want, when it hits the publish date, the event is actually running on that day so removing it from the list isn't quite correct.

**Is there a way I can delay removing it from the list until the end of the day?**

**p.s I don't want to use a plugin as I don't think it warrants it.**

---

I've found this:

```
$args = array(
   'posts_per_page' => 3,
   'meta_key' => 'event-start-date',
   'orderby' => 'meta_value',
   'order' => 'ASC',
   'meta_query' => array(
      array( 'key' => 'event-end-date', 'compare' => '>=', 'value' => date('Y-m-d') )
   )
);
query_posts($args);
```

I don't want to sort by a custom field so how can I do it by the post publish date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved this with:

```
function my_filter_where( $where = '' ) {
    global $wp_query;
    if (is_array($wp_query->query_vars['post_status'])) {

        if (in_array('future',$wp_query->query_vars['post_status'])) {
        // posts today into the future
        $where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('now')) . "'";
        }
    }
    return $where;
}
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'my_filter_where' );
```

And:

```
<?php
$wp_query = array(
        'post__not_in' => array(4269),
        'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),
        'post_type' => 'whatson',
        'exclude' => '4269',
        'posts_per_page' => 20,
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'post_status' =>array('future','published'));
query_posts($wp_query);
?>

                    <?php 
                    if ($wp_query->have_posts()) {
                    while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
                        Content
                    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop.
                    }  ?>

                    <?php if (function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) { wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $wp_query ) ); } ?>
```

Comment: Is this question related to your other one here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/17452086? It seems odd that exactly the same solution solves both.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just add a post_date WHERE statement to the query to search for posts? Then the post_status will have to be removed from the query, thus:

```
<?php $query_string = array( 'post__not_in' => array(4269), 'paged' => get_query_var('paged'), 'post_type' => 'whatson', 'exclude' => '4269', 'posts_per_page' => 20, 'order' => 'ASC'); ?>

// Create a new filtering function that will add our where clause to the query
function filter_where( $where = '' ) {
    $end_of_day = date('Y-m-d') . ' 23:59:59';
    $where .= " AND post_date < '$end_of_day' ";
    return $where;
}

add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
$query = new WP_Query( $query_string );
remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
```

Comment: Ok, great. I gave it a go but I was getting an error on my while loop - Fatal error: Call to a member function have_posts() on a non-object in /home/domain/public_html/wp-content/themes/default/whatson-archive.php on line 39

Comment: What does your while loop look like? do you use have_posts as a single function or does it look something like this: $query->have_posts();
In that case you probably used the wrong variable reference. Make sure that this is the variable $query.

Comment: Like this `<?php while ( $query_string->have_posts() ) : $query_string->the_post(); ?>`

Comment: try this: <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

Comment: Ok, very close but get this now `Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in /home/domain/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-pagenavi/core.php on line 217`

Comment: can you post the code on line 217 of /home/domain/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-pagenavi/core.php

Comment: Ok that's fixed (sorry didn't read the error properly). It doesn't currently show any posts, I haven't changed any of the code.